# Error query desde setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

Estoy intentando asociar el elemento seleccionado de una lista a otro elemento mediante una query en el *setOnClickListener* del *activity*, pero me sale el siguiente error:

> ```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.ruvenvi.mealplanner, PID: 31948
>     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
> ```

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anadir_recetas_menus)  
        var listaR_disponibles = emptyList<Receta>()
        val database = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this)
        val idMenu = intent.getIntExtra("idMenu", 0)

        database.recetas_en_menus().getRecetas_disponibles(idMenu).observe(this,{
            listaR_disponibles = it
            val adapter = RecetaAdapter(this, listaR_disponibles)
            lista_recetas_menus.adapter = adapter
        })
        lista_recetas_menus.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, idReceta->
            intent.putExtra("idMenu", idMenu)
            database.recetas_en_menus().setRecetaMenu(idMenu,listaR_disponibles[position].idReceta)
            val intent = Intent(this, MenuActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

La sentencia *setRecetaMenu* está declarada así:

```
@Dao
interface MenuRecetaDao {
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM recetas WHERE idReceta = (SELECT idReceta FROM recetas_menus WHERE idMenu = :idMenu)")
    fun getRecetasMenus(idMenu: Int): LiveData<List<Receta>>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM recetas WHERE idReceta NOT IN (SELECT idReceta FROM recetas_menus WHERE idMenu = :idMenu)")
    fun getRecetas_disponibles(idMenu: Int): LiveData<List<Receta>>

    @Transaction
    @Query("INSERT INTO recetas_menus VALUES (:idMenu, :idReceta)")
    fun setRecetaMenu(idMenu: Int, idReceta: Int)
}
```

¿Alguna idea de que puede estar fallando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el log claramente lo dice:

> Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially
> lock the UI for a long period of time.

No puede hacer operaciones con bases de datos en el hilo principal ya que se puede bloquear la interfaz por un largo periodo de tiempo, lo cual puede causar problemas de rendimiento y ANR.

Una solución pudiera ser Usando `newSingleThreadExecutor`

```kotlin
 lista_recetas_menus.setOnItemClickListener {
     parent,
     view,
     position,
     idReceta - >
     Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             intent.putExtra("idMenu", idMenu)
             database.recetas_en_menus().setRecetaMenu(idMenu, listaR_disponibles[position].idReceta)
             val intent = Intent(this, MenuActivity::class.java)
             startActivity(intent)
         }
     });

 }
```